# find the max. value of the area A(t)..

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $0<t≤1$ ,let $A(t)$ denote the area of the triangle bounded by the x-axis, the y-axis and the tangent line to the curve $y= \ln x$ at $(t,\ln t)$. Find the maximum value of area $A(t)$.

Comment: Can you add your thoughts about the problem? Where are you stuck at?

Answer (score 2):

The tangent to $y=\ln x$ at $(t,\ln t)$ is $y-\ln t=\dfrac{1}{t}(x-t)=\dfrac{x}{t}-1$. This allows you to find the area. Set the derivative of this equal to zero to get the required max./min. of the area function.